# migration from sql server 2000 to sql server 2012 API side

Tags: asp.net, database, api, iis, migration

In my firm  we need an upgrade and so we decided to upgrade our system. We have now an SQL Server 2000 IIS 5.0 and .Net version 2.

I have also also asp.net api that written also with vs 2000 with .net version 2 that connected to the server. The api is very simple and there no complex query to the server.
the upgrade we will do will transfer our system to server 2012 IIS 8 and because we will upgrade also our vs (2010? 2012? whats better?) the .net framework will update as well.
The migration itself between the databases will do a dba (I know he need to transfer the database first to 2005/2008 and only then to 2012) my job is to make sure the API will work.

Can you name all the things I should take care of them on the api side before the upgrade
(if there lack of information ask and I will tell)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some topics you may want to go through:

MSDN: Breaking Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2012, Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2012, Behavior Changes to SQL Server Features in SQL Server 2012

If your app uses any of the functionality that had changed you will need to make necessary changes to make it work smoothly in the new environment.

Also checkout the following link:

[Migration guide from Dell](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql%20server%202000%20database%20application%20migration&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEgQFjAA&url=http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/solutions/public/white_papers/SQL_2000_SQL_2008_Migration_Guide.pdf&ei=odYZUdz7Eo79qAHruICgBA&usg=AFQjCNF0-J6gEOkhVE64bWyxErL869-jiQ&bvm=bv.42261806,d.b2U)